# Where can I find the Riverside Mansion?

Tags: westerado

So, I don't know if I'm being stupid or what, but I can't, for the life of me, find the Riverside Mansion I bought for the waifu achievement. please help me.

Comment: Is this Westerado: Double Barreled on Steam, or something else?

Comment: I play it on xbox one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is to the East of Clintville. It has its own fast travel station (horse hitching post) once you go there the first time.

[image]

From the Sheriff's Office in Clintville, just head to the right until you get to the bridge. It is 2 screens away.

[image]
[image]

After you cross the bridge, you're there!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed this. This has been a huge help :)